# Will Updating an ObjectDataSource filtered from an EntityDataSource Update the EntityDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

In an ASP.NET Webform, using a Master/Details set up with a Gridview for selecting and a FormView for details, If I am programmatically binding the selected item to the FormView, like so:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new DataAccessLayer.SafetyEntities();
        var se = (from c in context.Employees
                  where c.EID == (long)GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value
                  select c).ToList();
        FormView1.DataSource = se;
        FormView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and I update the data in the FormView, will the changes be reflected in the original context?

Additionally, how would I programmatically update the entry I'm working with in the FormView?

I have read the following post : [How to populate an updateable FormView from an EntityDataSource with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056257/how-to-populate-an-updateable-formview-from-an-entitydatasource-with-filter) , but he is populating the formview differently than I am.

Should I populate the FormView like that instead?